# How do I start using a BLE beacon for my business?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I run a small self storage business with 3 physical locations in the UK.

Hopefully these are easy questions for someone as I've had no luck finding answers online. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

1. Would I benefit from the use of BLE beacons if placed at the entrance to each physical location (facility)? i.e. Would customers who pass within a certain proximity of our locations receive notifications?
2. Do I need an app (for my business) to link the beacons to or can the beacons be programmed via the Google Beacon Dashboard to simply direct customers to my website URL and/or Google My Business listing?
3. Do customers need to have installed a certain app to receive beacon notifications or will they receive these automatically when within reach of the BLE beacons?

Comment: The golden age is over, your app has to do the range scan for beacons in the proximity.

Comment: 1) Yes, if the customer has Beacon scanning app running. 2) Yes. You can use your custom app or use Google app or even use Eddyston URL beacons to advertise URLs. 3) Yes, customer need to have app running.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses emix and Mike; it's great to now know what is required in order to use beacons fully and efficiently. Not sure how many people in rural Lincolnshire are likely to have a beacon scanning app running which means they [beacons] are likely to be something that I have to 'park' for the time being and revisit when they become more widely used / recognised by consumers.